Deploy entire Customizations, Flow, Apex etc from a Developer Edition org to a new Production org
We have been doing configurations, development, and automations in a Salesforce developer edition org independent of a production instance(not a sandbox). We have now just acquired a new production instance and will like to push all the work from this developer org on there.
I have read that we can do this using Salesforce cli in Vscode. I am familiar with pushing Code from the CLI but I’m not sure how to push the entire metadata; customizations, objects, flows, etc using this tool.
My intention is to retrieve all customizations, flows etc from this developer org and then push everything to the new production org.
Any guidance will be appreciated and if there are other ways to achieve this same thing I’m open to new suggestions, thanks!

Apex code is just one type of metadata the CLI can handle. These are pulled and pushed the same way. There are some types of metadata that are not supported by the CLI, but most are.

Depending on your long-term plans for managing changes to your PROD org, it is worth considering the various devops tools - DevOps Center, Gearset, Copado, etc.

As mentioned above, you can pull all the other items, not just code, from the source org.  The standard procedure would be to retrieve everything to files, then check into source control like git, then deploy to the target org.
You first step will be to learn how to use the metadata operations in the CLI to pull the items you want.  Hit the documentation for that.
